# formula for knowing the fibonacci character at certain index

Tags: math

Is there any formula you can directly apply for knowing a fibonacci character within a word without having to construct the word from scratch.

For example. Let's consider:

```
0 a
1 b
2 ba
3 bab
4 babba
5 babbabab
```

Is there a way to find what character is in w(4) at index 3 which in this case is b as
w(4) equals babba provided you know beforehand that w(4) has 5 characters?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: It's simply the most logical reply to your reaction.

Answer (score 0):

That would have been really easy to google.

Note: there are no words, like w(4), they are just construction steps of the single infinite word.

You can find the closed formula and its description on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_word#Closed-form_expression_for_individual_digits).